# Post a model: the parent in the JSON or not?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and want to store a model called "domain." A domain belongs to an organization.

**Route**

```
Route::apiResource('organizations/{organization}/domains', 
    DomainController::class)
    ->whereUuid(['organization', 'domain']);
```

As the route is:

```
{{path}}/organizations/1a52ef80-9f9e-4172-9d8c-e63595ad3712/domains
```

I have two choices to send the data to the server. First, I can post something like the following.

```
{
    "organization_id": "1a52ef80-9f9e-4172-9d8c-e63595ad3712",
    "domain_name": "domain name"
}
```

Or without the *organization_id* since it is in the path.

```
{
    "domain_name": "domain name"
}
```

What is a good practice? With or without the parent in the JSON?

Comment: IMO, If you are passing the `organization_id` in the URL then passing the same value in the body doesn't seem to be beneficial. I would prefer the second option which is without the `organization_id` in the body.